# Allow access to all files from only 1 IP address and redirect all others to other file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm not sure if this has been answered before but I tried looking for it. Anyways, I'm currently developing a website but I would like to make the actual site content only accessible from my IP address. I then want .htaccess to redirect all other IP address to a separate file on my server. That one file would be called `subscribe.php`.

I've tried a couple things but nothing provided me with the result I wanted. I know my server allows `.htaccess` to be used since I've used it to change some other things such as preventing caches.

Comment: RTFM: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer :p The link seemed to have the details I was looking for but I have no idea how to use it for my specific case :s I'm still pretty new to Apache and `.htaccess`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do that. Add the following in your `.htaccess` file:

**Code:**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.67.89
RewriteRule index.php$ /subscribe.php [R=301,L]
```

**Alternative solution:**

```
<?php $allow = array("123.456.789", "456.789.123", "789.123.456"); //allowed IPs

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow)) {

    header("Location: http://domain.tld/subscribe.php"); //redirect

    exit();

} ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: An attacker could simply set the X-Forwarded-For header and bypass this filter.

Comment: I know the method isn't foolproof - those extra fields are arbitrary HTTP headers provided by the client, and anyone could easily spoof that. But do you have any better suggestions here?

Comment: @douggard Any example about bypassing this `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` filter? I want to test my app's security.

Comment: Get a "modify headers plugin" for Chrome or Firefox. Set an X-Forwarded-For header to the IP address you allow. Visit the page from an IP not allowed.

Really, you should just remove the X_FORWARDED_FOR check, unless you're usually going through a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for the same.

Add following in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^80\.40\.20\.[0-9]$ # your ip here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subscribe.php
RewriteRule .? /subscribe.php [R,L]
</IfModule>
```