# How to generate and validate access tokens for each user session?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I've set this website which consumes an API using JS, in the client-side. Although, it's not a good solution as it exposes my API account token.

In this way, I've decided to make the API calls using PHP, after the server is triggered by some JS Fetch request. But, with this solution, bad boys would still be able to read my code, copy the PHP file URL and enjoy my API Plan.

To solve that I've read some questions and some answers around here which tell people to generate a token, store in the session and then send it with the request to the server, so it can make sure the request was made from my own website. BUT I DON'T EVEN KNOW HOW TO SEARCH FOR THAT!

For now, I'm basically using DOM events to trigger the Fetch API (JS in the client side) which requests a PHP file in my server to make the actual API request and return the data:

```js
fetch('myServerScript.php') // How can I block people from using this file?
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    //Handles Data
  })
```

```html
// This file is in my backend and is named myServerScript.php
<?php

$response = @file_get_contents('https://ddd.pricez.com.br/ddds/87.json');

echo $response;
```

What I really expect is:

- Hide my API token in the backend;
- Block requests to my PHP file, unless they're from my own website;
- The actual code for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Put your token in some other path. If your website is hosted under /var/www store your token somewhere else /etc/myapp/config (for example). And then read the token in php.

If your server is configured correctly nobody should be able to see your code, but even if they could this adds another layer of security.

If you use something like symfony you will get configuration similar to what I have described out of the box.

Comment: How can I read this token, using PHP? How can I block people from using this resquest URI?

Comment: Can you see the mock code I've added to the description?

Answer (score 0):

- There are multiple ways to securely handle tokens for authorization. For example [oAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/).
- You can only allow specific IPs to access your APIs. You can restrict
  IPs in `.htaccess` for Apache or at application level in APIs.

  [Allow access to all files from only 1 IP address and redirect all others to other file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704961/allow-access-to-all-files-from-only-1-ip-address-and-redirect-all-others-to-othe/17705105)
- You can also configure your server to prevent directory listing. You can
  use `.htaccess` for Apache. Your source code
  will be protected.

  [How do I disable directory browsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

Comment: Can you see the mock code I've added to the description? I'm not sure if it applies to my situation.

Comment: Client is in client's hand but you can protect your backend code as I discussed in my answer. You can add IP filtering in your backend code.